# Sqlite RecyclerView No adapter attached skipping layout

Tags: android

I don't see all the tables loaded in the database displayed tells me that the recyclerview is not attached to the layout.

DATABASE

```
public class SqliteHelperDB extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static SqliteHelperDB       dbInstance          = null;
    private static SQLiteDatabase   db;

    //TODO NOME DEL DATABASE
    private static final String DATABASE = "Gticket.db";
    //TODO DATABASE VERSION
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

    //TODO OVERRIDE COSTRUCTOR
    public SqliteHelperDB(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE, null, DB_VERSION);
    }

    public static SqliteHelperDB getInstance(Context context)
    {
        if (dbInstance == null)
        {
            dbInstance = new SqliteHelperDB(context);
            db = dbInstance.getWritableDatabase();
        }
        return dbInstance;
    }

    //TODO CREAZIONE TicketInfo TABELLA usando SQL query
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        this.db = db;

        final String SQL_CREATE_QUESTIONS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " +
                TABLE_NAME + " ( " +
                TicketTable.T_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                TicketTable.T_NUMBERT + " TEXT, " +
                TicketTable.T_REDATTORE + " TEXT, " +
                TicketTable.T_TARGA + " TEXT, " +
                TicketTable.T_DATAA + " TEXT, " +
                TicketTable.T_MATERIALE + " TEXT, " +
                TicketTable.T_DATAC + " TEXT" +
                ")";

        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_QUESTIONS_TABLE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        //TODO rilascio la tabella delle versioni precedenti
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TicketInfo" + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);

    }
    //TODO AGGIUNGERE UN NUOVO TICKET
     public void saveNewTicket(Ticket newticket){

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
         ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
         values.put(TicketTable.T_NUMBERT,newticket.getTicket());
         values.put(TicketTable.T_REDATTORE,newticket.getRedattore());
         values.put(TicketTable.T_TARGA,newticket.getTarga());
         values.put(TicketTable.T_DATAA,newticket.getDataApertura());
         values.put(TicketTable.T_MATERIALE,newticket.getMaterialeGuasto());
         values.put(TicketTable.T_DATAC,newticket.getDataChiusura());

         //TODO INSERIMENTO DELLE COLONNE
         db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,values);
         db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Ticketinfo" + TABLE_NAME );
         db.close();
     }

     //TODO AGGIORNAMENTO TICKET
    public int UpdateTicket(Ticket newticket){

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(TicketTable.T_NUMBERT,newticket.getTicket());
        values.put(TicketTable.T_REDATTORE,newticket.getRedattore());
        values.put(TicketTable.T_TARGA,newticket.getTarga());
        values.put(TicketTable.T_DATAA,newticket.getDataApertura());
        values.put(TicketTable.T_MATERIALE,newticket.getMaterialeGuasto());
        values.put(TicketTable.T_DATAC,newticket.getDataChiusura());

        //TODO INSERIMENTO DELLE COLONNE
        return  db.update(TABLE_NAME,values, TicketTable.T_ID + " = ? " ,new String[]{String.valueOf(newticket.getId())});

    }
     //TODO ELIMINAZIONE TICKET
    public void DeleteTicketRecord(Ticket newticket){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        db.delete(TABLE_NAME , TicketTable.T_ID + " = ? " ,new String[]{String.valueOf(newticket.getId())});
        db.close();
    }


    public Cursor getAllRecords(){

        db = getReadableDatabase();
        return db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM  " + TicketTable.TABLE_NAME,null);


    }

    public List<Ticket> getAllTicket() {

        List<Ticket> TicketList = new ArrayList<>();

        //TODO SELEZIONE TUTTA LA QUERY
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TicketTable.TABLE_NAME;
        db = getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery,null);

        //TODO looping attraverso tutte le righe e aggiungendo alla lista
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do{
                Ticket newticket = new Ticket();
                newticket.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
                newticket.setTicket(cursor.getString(1));
                newticket.setRedattore(cursor.getString(2));
                newticket.setTarga(cursor.getString(3));
                newticket.setDataApertura(cursor.getString(4));
                newticket.setMaterialeGuasto(cursor.getString(5));
                newticket.setDataChiusura(cursor.getString(6));

                //TODO AGGIUNGE TICKET INFORMATION ALLA LISTA
                TicketList.add(newticket);
            }while(cursor.moveToNext());

        }
         cursor.close();
        return TicketList;
    }
}
```

VISUALIZZA(here must display the db records via private void populaterecyclerView)

```
public class Visualizza extends AppCompatActivity  {

    private ArrayList<Ticket> adapter;
    private List<Ticket> listTicket;
    private SqliteHelperDB db;
    private TicketAdapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    Toolbar mToolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.recyclerview);

        /*//todo modalita FullScreen
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);*/
        mToolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbarLayout);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        BuildRecyclearView();
        populaterecyclerView();

    }

    //TODO Visualizzzare le schede dal DB
    private void populaterecyclerView() {

        db = SqliteHelperDB.getInstance(this);
        listTicket = db.getAllTicket();

        if (listTicket != null)
        {
            adapter = new ArrayList<Ticket>(listTicket);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        }

    }




    //TODO Costruzione della RecyclerView
    public void BuildRecyclearView () {
        //todo dichiarazione adapter e chiamiamo il suo costruttore passandogli i parametri necessari
        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.miorecyclerView);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        //todo assegnazione LinearLayoutManager alla RecyclearView
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        //todo set LinearLayoutManager
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        //mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    }

    //TODO Procedura ToolBar Menu
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu (Menu menu){

        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);
        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
        searchView.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                mAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                return false;
            }
        });
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the full code? mAdapter is never set, it's always null

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `RecyclerView`:

```
app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
```

Comment: tried but it doesn't work, I don't see any records in the Layout